# Add translatable=false to String resource using build.gradle in Android?

Tags: java, android, gradle

Is it possible to add translatable=false to String resource using build.gradle?

I have 
resValue 'string', 'app_name', name 
but i want to make it untranslatable. (translatable=false)
Is it actually possible?

Comment: Not in the gradle file. You do that in your strings.xml. Where the app name, among all the other strings should reside.

Comment: Don't provide a translation for the value

Comment: @ModularSynth no, i want to do it WITH BUILD.GRADLE, not with xml file. I know how to edit xmls.

Comment: I gave you the solution. Have a nice day.

Comment: @ModularSynth, not really. I need to put app_name which should be untranslatable depending on buildFlavor , i don't want to edit xml each time i am making a new build, that's why i am looking for the way to do it with build.gradle

Comment: @ModularSynth not exactly what i was going to do first, but found a way to do the same with xml. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradle plugin for Android **doesn't support** this.
You cannot add `translatable=false` in your `gradle file`.

Comment: Thank you. Will need to look for another way.

Comment: there still are workarounds, so I'd not say word `cannot`

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways to achieve what you want. Firs 2 ways are to ignore the missing translations, so you don't need `translatable` attribute at all. You can make it ignore using XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  tools:ignore="MissingTranslation" > <!--this line-->

  <!-- your strings here; no need now for the translatable attribute -->

</resources>
```

or using gradle option:

```
android {
     lintOptions {
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
    }
}
```

3rd option is to pre-process the resources by gradle replacing lines in any source file:

inside a build variant:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant -> 
    if (variant.name.toLowerCase().contains("nuset")) {
        variant.mergeResources.doLast {
            def dir = new File("${buildDir}/intermediates/res/merged/${variant.dirName}")
            println("Resources" + dir)
            dir.eachFileRecurse { file ->
                if (file.name.endsWith(".xml")) {
                    String content = file.getText('UTF-8')
                    if (content != null && content.contains('<string name="app_name">')) {
                        println("Replacing app name in " + file)
                        content = content.replace('<string name="app_name">', '<string name="app_name" translatable="false">')
                        file.write(content, 'UTF-8')
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

so it will replace all occurrences of `<string name="app_name">` with `<string name="app_name" translatable="false">` not in original sources, but in merged (prepared for packaging) sources